# 'list' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

Tags: python, pygame

**FIXED**: My issue was with assigning the results of a custom method I created to use in conjunction with zip() to my .rect attribute (code below). The method returned a list object which was being assigned to the .rect attribute of my projectile object, changing its object type from 'pygame.Rect' to 'list'. The fix involved storing the 'list' result in the .topleft property of the .rect property, which is a 'list' that pygame.Rect derives its position from. Thanks so much Brien for the help!

**ORIGINAL POST**:

So, I'm trying to use the pygame method pygame.sprite.spritecollide() in order to check if a bullet has hit an enemy.

Except I'm getting this **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\PyProjects\pygamedev-shame\testGame.py", line 61, in <module>
    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, live_enemies, True)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1337, in spritecollide
    spritecollide = sprite.rect.colliderect
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'colliderect'
```

My **code** looks like this:

```
live_enemies = pygame.sprite.Group(enemies)

    for bullet in player.projectiles:
        cur_bullet = pygame.sprite.Group(bullet)
        bullet.move(seconds)
        bullet.update()
        screen.blit(bullet.surface, bullet.rect)
        pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, live_enemies, True)
        if bullet.rect[0] > screen_dim[0] or bullet.rect[0] < 0 or bullet.rect[len(bullet.pos) - 1] > screen_dim[1] or bullet.rect[len(bullet.pos) - 1] < 0:
            player.projectiles.remove(bullet)
```

The **projectile class** looks like this:

```
class projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #ctor
    def __init__(self, pos, imgPath, face, speed):
        #extending sprite
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #setup gfx
        self.surface = pygame.image.load(imgPath)
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos

        #init projectile vars
        self.facing = face
        self.orient(self.facing)
        self.speed = speed
        self.pos = pos
        self.dest_vector = pos

    #move the object
    def move(self, cr):
        moverate = cr*self.speed
        move_vector = self.facing
        #normalize diagonal movement
        if sum(map(abs, move_vector)) == 2:
            move_vector = [p/1.4142 for p in move_vector]

        move_vector = [moverate*p for p in move_vector]

        #set the destination vector
        self.dest_vector = map(sum, zip(self.dest_vector, move_vector))

    #orient the sprite
    def orient(self, face):
        rot = math.atan2(face[0],face[1])
        rot = math.degrees(rot) - 90
        self.surface = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, rot)

    #update the object
    def update(self):
        #interpolate movement over frames
        self.rect = map(alg.w_avg, zip(self.rect, self.dest_vector))
```

I think I have some sort of problem with projectile not being considered a sprite, but that seems weird since I have the super constructor and inheritance correct, as far as I can tell. The issue might be with the way a for loop regards items in a list, but I'm not sure how to correct that.

Can I get some insight to what the error is exactly and what I can do to fix it?

**EDIT**: The issue might actually be with my **w_avg method** which looks like this:

```
def w_avg(aset):
        slow = 3
        return ((aset[0] * (slow - 1)) + aset[1]) / slow
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to make sure the values are of the types you expect, instead of just guessing. If you just log (`print`, `logging.info`, whatever) `type(bullet)` and `type(live_enemies)` right before calling `spritecollide`, that will immediately prove or rule out the possibility that projectile isn't a sprite (or live_enemies isn't a sprite group).

Comment: type(bullet) returns as <class 'projectile.projectile'>

Comment: If I were smarter, I would have asked you to also log `type(bullet.rect)`, which would have solved the problem. But since Brien figured it out before you even got a chance to do any debugging, everything worked out fine. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in your `update` function you need to construct a `pygame.Rect`out of   `self.rect`  because `map` returns a list type.  Right now, you are trying to call a method of a `pygame.Rect` on a `list` object, which certainly will not work.

I don't know what your `alg.w_avg` function returns, so you may have to do something more complicated than a simple cast, but I believe that is the source of your problem.  A potential solution is (if `alg.w_avg` returns something 'nice' enough to be easily allow a `Rect` to be constructed from it) :

```
self.rect = Rect(map(alg.w_avg, zip(self.rect, self.dest_vector)))
```

**Edit:**

Seeing your `w_avg` method, I believe what you are going to want to do is

```
self.rect.topleft = map(alg.w_avg, zip(self.rect, self.dest_vector))
```

or some other location (`center`, etc.) on `self.rect`.

Comment: Ah, that might be it! I added the w_avg method to the bottom of the post. What is it that I should be doing in order to ensure that the result of w_avg is interpreted as a pygame.Rect?

Comment: "cast" is a misleading term of Python; it's better to say that you have to build a `pygame.Rect` out of the list. But otherwise, this answer is a nice explanation, and looks like the right problem.

Comment: @abarnert, you're completely right.  I couldn't really think of a better word for it.